# How to add an ImageView to a ListItem?

Tags: android, list, android-layout, listview, android-listview

[image]

here is my list view. I want to add one common image to all items. How to add common icon/image in this every item in the list. i have gone through many tutorials. Please someone help me.

sorry for asking the same question again friends.

Comment: you have customize the list adapter

Comment: Follow this tutorials http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Post your custom list item code

Comment: @HarishGodara i got the list of item from database.

Comment: I'm talking about the view(layout) of item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an Image to each of your listitems, you will need a **custom layout** for your items and a **custom-adapter**.

Code example:

```
ArrayList<YourItem> items = new ArrayList<YourItem>();
items.add(new YourItem(R.drawable.image, "Yourtext");
// add more items...

YourCustomAdapter adapter = ne YourCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_item, items);
ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is a **full example:**

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

In the full example it is explained in detail how to create the custom-adapter and the custom-layout.

Comment: ya i go through it. may be it helps for me.

Comment: i am getting my list item from data base. so it contains 10 or 20. i dont know about the details of the item.

Comment: here "Yourtext" is mentioned which one.

Comment: He needs a custom layout, but not necessarily a custom adapter. In this case, a **SimpleCursorAdapter** should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

http://download.androidhive.info/download.php
try this tutorial customized list view it will help you make your list more beautiful lol

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: actually pete I don't have to spoon feed him he has the link he can check it for himself and do what needs doing

Comment: hi satine before having a go at me, please read the section about how to answer questions on this site

Comment: sorry pete im not gonna answer anymore since this is out of the topic thanks for your time and sorry